# How to return multiple objects in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am working on an e-commerce app and want customers to be able to order several items. Currently they can only order one and i am having a hard time figuring out how i can achieve this.
in my menu template i return all the items in their category as follows:

```
{% for category in categories %}
 <h5> {{ category.title }} </h5>
  {% for item in category.item.all %}
   <li><a href="{% url item_order item.id %}">{{item.name}}<span> {{item.price}}frw</span></li><a/>
```

OnClick, each item redirects to a form where you can order the quantity. here is the view:

```
def show_item(request,id):
    # need to evaluate the HTTP method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = forms.PartialOrderItemForm(request.POST,instance=a)
        # check validation of posted data
        if form.is_valid():
            order.add_to_order(request)
            # if test cookie worked, get rid of it
            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()
            url =urlresolvers.reverse('order_index')
            # redirect to order page
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        # it's a GET, create the unbound from. Note request as a Kwarg
        form = forms.PartialOrderItemForm(request.GET)
    # set the test cookie on our first GET request
    request.session.set_test_cookie()
    context={
#       'categories':categories,
        'form':form,
#       'menu':menu,

    }
    return render_to_response('item.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

At some point, the above view calls the following view, that is after validating the form `order.add_to_order(request)`

## add an item to order

```
def add_to_order(request):  
    postdata = request.POST.copy()
    # get item slug from post data, return blank if empty
#   item_slug = postdata.get('item_slug','')
    #get quantity added, return 0 if empty
    quantity = postdata.get('quantity',0)
    # fetch the item or return  missing page error_message
    i = get_object_or_404(Item,pk=1)
    i.orderitem_set.all()
    # get items in order
    order_items = get_order_items(request)
    item_in_orders = False
    # check to see if item is already in order
    for order_item in order_items:
        if order_item.item.id == i.id:
            #update the quantity if found
            order_item.augment_quantity(quantity)
            item_in_orders = True
    if not item_in_orders:
        # creat and save a new order item
        oi = OrderItem()
        oi.order_id = _order_id(request)
        oi.quantity = quantity
        oi.item = i
        oi.save()
```

Once the form is validated, the order is shown in the order page. here is the view that does this

```
def show_order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Remove':
            order.remove_from_order(request)
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Update':
            order.update_order(request)
    order_items = order.get_order_items(request)
#   page_title  = 'F4L order' 
    order_subtotal = order.order_subtotal(request)

    context = {
        'order_items':order_items,
        'order_subtotal':order_subtotal,
    }
    return render_to_response('public/order.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

here is part of the template for the order page.

```
<tbody>
    {% if order_items %}
     {% for item in order_items %}
    <tr>
     <td>

       {{ item.item.name }}

     </td>
     <td>{{ item.item.price }}<span> frw</span></td>
     <td class="right">
      <form method="post" action="." class="order">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
       <input type="text" name="quantity" value="{{ item.quantity }}" id="quantity" size="2" class="quantity" max_length="5" />
       <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{{ item.id }}" />
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
      </form>
```

Here is what is happening, when i order the first item with `pk=1` it works out properly, but then when i order the second item or any other and fill in the form, instead the order page returns the first item always.
 How do you think i should go about this.

Comment: Please simplfy your problem. Please mention problem is in which function (or at what line).

Comment: sorry about that, the problem is i can only make an order for one item and i want to be able to make an order for several items. So i think the problem is in the `show_order` view and its template that is mentioned last.